# In xmonad, how can I promote the next window in the stack to the master window?

Tags: xmonad

I often find myself pressing `Mod-Tab` and then `Mod-Enter` to switch focus to the next window in the stack and move it to the master window.

Is there possibly a keyboard shortcut that accomplishes this in one keystroke instead of two? Otherwise, what would I need to place in my `xmonad.hs` to create such a shortcut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extremely late answer, but perhaps still helpful to somebody:

The functions that you need are: `windows $ W.swapMaster . W.focusDown`, where: `swapMaster` and `focusDown` are imported from `XMonad.StackSet`:

```
import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W
```

A minimal `xmonad.hs`:

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Util.EZConfig
import qualified Data.Map as M
import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W

main = xmonad $ def `additionalKeysP` myKeys

myKeys = [ ("M-a", windows $ W.swapMaster . W.focusDown )]
```

Here, the keybinding is `Mod-a`.